# Using sp_HElpText to view stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

How can I view a stored procedure by using `sp_HelpText`?

I am not sure about its exact spelling? I am looking for something like below,

```
EXEC sp_HelpText WHERE storedprocedurename Like '%spInsert%'
```

Is it possible way to view the stored procedure?

Comment: You can search for the stored procedures using: `SELECT name
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE name LIKE '%spInsert%'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create below stored procedure in your database. It will helpful to you in future also.

```
EXEC Searchinall 'TextSpName'    

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Searchinall] 
    (@strFind AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON; 
        --to find string in all procedures        
        BEGIN
            SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) SP_Name,
                   OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) SP_Definition
            FROM   sys.procedures
            WHERE  OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%' + @strFind + '%'
        END
    END
```

It will provide all matched store procedure list, which contains/using given keyword. `TextSpName`